# Functions executed without waiting for Promise.all call

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a multidimensional array of promises, but the execution of `executeMethod` occurs before the initial `for` loop ends and the code reaches the second `for` loop and `Promise.all`.

`executeMethod` is of course an async function.

```
const MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_PROMISES = 100;
const promisesArray: Promise<void>[][] = [];
let promiseArrayIndex = 0;
let innerPromiseArrayIndex = 0;

const objectsList = [......];

for (const bucketObject of objectsList) {
    if (innerPromiseArrayIndex === MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_PROMISES) {
      innerPromiseArrayIndex = 0;
      promiseArrayIndex++;

      promisesArray[promiseArrayIndex] = [];
    }

    promisesArray[promiseArrayIndex][innerPromiseArrayIndex] = (
      executeMethod(bucketObject)
    );
    innerPromiseArrayIndex++;
}

for (let i=0; i< promiseArrayIndex; i++) {
  await Promise.all(promisesArray[i]);
}
```

I want the executions to occur only after `for (const bucketObject of objectsList)` ends and I call `Promise.all` per each Promises array.

Please advise how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `Promise.all` that executes anything, it's the `executeMethod(bucketObject)` call. And those all happen synchronously in your loop, before you start waiting for anything.

To batch your executions, use

```
const MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_PROMISES = 100;
const objectsList = [......];

for (let index = 0; index<objectsList.length; index+=MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_PROMISES) {
   const promisesArray: Promise<void>[] = objectsList.slice(index, index+MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_PROMISES).map(executeMethod);
   await Promise.all(promisesArray);
}
```

Comment: But if I understand correctly  `promisesArray` will contain more 100 promises? Ot will it still be an array of array of promises?

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev `slice` never takes more than 100 objects from the list. (Usually 100, possibly less in the last iteration).